# Return value directly from CompletableFuture.thenAccept

Tags: java, concurrency, java-8, completable-future

I am trying to return a list from my `CompletableFuture` like this:

```
public List<Provider> get() {
    CompletableFuture<List<Provider>> providersResponse = getSomeData();
    return providersResponse.thenAccept((List<Provider> providers) -> {
        return providers;
    });
}
```

It fails with "unexpected return type though. How can I return the result in an async way?

Comment: Note that you can write the argument to `thenAccept` like this shorter and clearer: `.thenAccept(providers -> providers)`

Comment: And how is the caller of `get()` supposed to deal with the spurious asynchronous `List` modification?

Comment: @Holger Could you elaborate? I do not understand what `spurious asynchronous List modification` is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a fundamental contradiction in your goal. You can have only either, `get()` returning a complete, directly usable list or “return the result in an async way”.

If the method `List<Provider> get()` is supposed to return a `List` which can be used by the caller without restrictions, it can’t stay an asynchronous operation, as the operation must have been completed when `get()` returns. This can be achieved as simple as calling `join()`, to wait for the completion and get the result:

```
public List<Provider> get() {
    CompletableFuture<List<Provider>> providersResponse = getSomeData();
    return providersResponse.join();
}
```

or just

```
public List<Provider> get() {
    return getSomeData().join();
}
```

This effectively turns the potentially asynchronous operation of `getSomeData()` into a synchronous operation.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43489414/2711488), using

```
public List<Provider> get() {
    List<Provider> providers = new ArrayList<>();
    CompletableFuture<List<Provider>> providersResponse = getSomeData();
    providersResponse.thenAccept(providers::addAll);
    return providers;
}
```

does not wait for the completion of the operation, but returns a new `ArrayList` after scheduling an `addAll` operation, whose execution is entirely out of control of this method.

This is an asynchronous operation, so when `get()` returns, the `List` might still be empty, but get updated at a later time by an arbitrary thread. Since `ArrayList` is not thread safe, the perceived state doesn’t have to be either, empty or completed, it may be an arbitrary in-between state, not even required to be consistent. Be prepared for strange exceptions, impossible-looking situations or other surprises when using that code.

When you fix that code by using a thread safe `List` implementation, you still have the problem that the returned `List` might be empty when queried and get filled at an arbitrary point of time outside of the caller’s control. That’s not fixable, as said at the beginning, it’s the fundamental problem of wanting an asynchronous operation but returning a `List`.

The `CompletableFuture` is already an encapsulation of a potentially asynchronous operation, so if you want the operation to stay asynchronous, just return the `CompletableFuture<List<Provider>>` to the caller, to allow to gain control. Otherwise, if you want the caller to receive a `List` which can be used without restrictions, wait for the completion before returning the result, e.g. via `join()`.

Comment: I have a similar use case but am new to CompletableFuture.  I am trying to replace AsyncTask [also ExecutorService.submit() with .get()] to load a List of CardViews from Room database to the UI.  Your comment about returning an empty List has me nervous about even using CompletableFuture.  Would appreciate any thoughts or ideas here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67294345/android-how-to-load-list-from-room-using-completablefuture

Comment: We can return CompletableFuture to the caller, but the caller would at some point in time need response, what to do there then? use join ?

Comment: @inquisitive yes, that’s meant with “allow the caller to gain control”. The caller can decide to perform some other actions concurrently but the caller may call `join()` when the value is required. Alternatively, the caller may chain other dependent actions, to be executed upon completion.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public List<Provider> get() {
    List<Provider> providers = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
    CompletableFuture<List<Provider>> providersResponse = getSomeData();
    providersResponse.thenAccept(providers::addAll);
    return providers;
}
```

Comment: This is broken as the caller can get an empty `ArrayList` on which another thread might call `addAll` at an arbitrary time. `ArrayList` is not thread safe.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Even with the synchronized list, it remains very inconvenient for the caller as he will have no means to know when the list will be filled in – in particular when `getSomeData()` fails or returns an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public List<Provider> get() {
    return getSomeData().get();
}
```

Comment: CompletableFuture.get() is blocking so it would lock the thread no?

Comment: You must decide if you want your get() to block or not. It can be async and return a CompletableFuture<List<Provider>> or be blocking and return List<Provider>. it can not be async and return a plain List...