# Reduce List<CompletableFuture<T>>

Tags: java, java-stream, completable-future

When `ints` is given:

```
List<Integer> ints = IntStream.range(0, 1000).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

With Java Stream API, we can reduce them

```
MyValue myvalue = ints
        .parallelStream()
        .map(x -> toMyValue(x))
        .reduce((t, t2) -> t.combine(t2))
        .get();
```

In this example, what important to me are...

- items will be reduced in multiple threads
- early mapped items will be reduced early
- not all result of `toMyValue()` will be loaded at the same time

Now I want to do same processing by `CompletableFuture` API.

To do map, I did:

```
List<CompeletableFuture<MyValue>> myValueFutures = ints
        .stream()
        .map(x -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> toMyValue(x), MY_THREAD_POOL))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And now I have no idea how to reduce `List<CompeletableFuture<MyValue>> myValueFutures` to get single `MyValue`.

Parallel stream provides convenient APIs but because of these problems I want not to use Stream API:

- parallel stream is hard to stop the stage during processing.
- parallel stream's active worker count can exceed the parallelism when some workers blocked by IO. This helps to maximize cpu utilization but memory overhead can occur(even OOM).

Any way to reduce CompetableFutures? one by one with out stream reduce api?

Comment: @Holger: Please, post it as an answer. Now the potential answerers would fear the copying suspicion which might cause this question will be left unanswered. And I believe this is a nice question that deserves a proper answer.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis didn’t have the time to write a full answer when I wrote the comment. If someone writes a full-fledged answer around that straight-forward one-liner (as someone did), they should not fear copying suspicion. In fact, posting it here has the intention to invite to copy and use it, not to avoid it.

Answer (score 4):

It's interesting that in your initial example you already mention a method you have `combine`, while for `CompletableFuture` there is a dedicated method, just for that : `thenCombine` (and its two brothers `thenCombineAsync`).

So considering that you have something like:

```
static class MyValue {
    final int x;

    MyValue(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    MyValue combine(MyValue v){
        return new MyValue(this.x + v .x);
    }
}

static MyValue toMyValue(int x) {
    return new MyValue(x);
}
```

And:

```
List<CompletableFuture<Integer>> list = 
    IntStream.range(0, 4)
             .mapToObj(x -> supplyAsync(() -> x))
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You could use one of the `thenCombine` methods and achieve what you want via:

```
MyValue value =
    list.stream()
        .map(x -> x.thenApply(YourClass::toMyValue))
        .reduce((left, right) -> left.thenCombine(right, MyValue::combine))
        .orElse(CompletableFuture.completedFuture(new MyValue(0)))
        .join();
```

If you want to execute the combine action in a *predictable* thread, you need a pool for that, or an overloaded method, like:

```
.reduce((left, right) -> left.thenCombineAsync(right, MyValue::combine, MY_THREAD_POOL))
```

Comment: Giving dedicated pool to combineAsync in "Stream Reduce" will genetate twice number of threads, because just wrapping threads will run for reduce in ForkJoinPool.commonPool. Isn't it?

Comment: @JihunNo I don't understand what you ask. Where did you get the "twice" from? How big that pool is - it is up to you. If you want to use a dedicated pool or common pool, is an entirely different question.

Comment: One thread  execute or waiting for `(left, right) -> left.thenCombine(right, MyValue::combine)` in ForkJoinPool.common , the other thread for execute `left.thenCombineAsync(right, MyValue::combine, Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())` in `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` pool.

Comment: @JihunNo I really, _really_ don't understand what you are trying to say. may be open a separate question?

Comment: OK. I agree my explain might not enough detail or correct.

Comment: @JihunNo that's OK. you can accept any answer that helped you here and open a new one, may be with a clear explanation and people will help. I am sure

Comment: The OP does already have `MY_THREAD_POOL`, so it’s preferable to use that pool. Besides that, calling `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` every time the reduction function is evaluated, defeats the entire purpose of executors/ thread pools.

Answer (score 3):

Basically you need to wait for the results of all the `CompletableFuture`s and combine then to obtain the result required.

There are several approaches for that, but the `CompletableFuture` class provides the method [`allOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf(java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...)) that can be used for that purpose.

When I have to do with a similar problem I like to follow the Tomasz Nurkiewicz [advice](https://www.nurkiewicz.com/2013/05/java-8-completablefuture-in-action.html) and perform this kind of computation in the following way.

As suggested in the article, first, let's define the following convenient method: `allOf` receives arguments as varargs and doesn't return a future of aggregated results; this method will allow you to overcome those drawbacks so you can pass a `Collection` as argument and return the `List` of actual results instead of `Void`.

```java
private static <T> CompletableFuture<List<T>> sequence(List<CompletableFuture<T>> futures) {
    CompletableFuture<Void> allDoneFuture =
        CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futures.size()]));
    return allDoneFuture.thenApply(v ->
            futures.stream().
                    map(future -> future.join()).
                    collect(Collectors.<T>toList())
    );
}
```

With this handy method in place you can reduce your values with something like:

```java
final CompletableFuture<List<MyValue>> allDone = sequence(myValueFutures);

// Please, see also for alternate approaches
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43489281/return-value-directly-from-completablefuture-thenaccept
final List<MyValue> myValues = allDone.join();

final Optional<MyValue> optResult = myValues.stream().
  reduce((t, t2) -> t.combine(t2))
;

// Process the returned value as you consider appropriate
final MyValue result = optResult.get();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question of going from `List<CompeletableFuture<MyValue>>` to a single `MyValue`

There's a library com.spotify:completable-futures which can easily reduce a `List<CompletableFuture<T>>` to `CompletableFuture<List<T>>`. That might be the most common use case.

https://github.com/spotify/completable-futures